# Using object's method in the same object

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

Need help. I've got a library called Rigged, similar to jQuery.
This code is not complete, it's just an example of my code (my lib has over 500 lines yet)

```
(function () {
     var arr = [];
     var Rigged = function ( selector ) {
           return Rigged.fn.init( selector );
     };

     Rigged.fn = Rigged.prototype = {
           map: function ( callback ) {
                  var results = arr, i = 0;
                  for ( ; i < this.length; i++) {
                        results.push(callback.call(this, this[i], i));
                  }
                  return results;
           },

           each: function (callback) {
                 return this.map(callback);
           },

           // this is just example of my code
           css: function (attr, value) {
                 if (attr == 'display') {
                       return this.each(function (current) {
                              current.style.display = value;
                       });
                 }
           },

           hide: function () {
                 return this.each(function (current) {
                      // here's a problem
                      current.css('display', 'none');
                 });
           }

     };


     Rigged.init = Rigged.fn.init = function (selector) {
          var elset, i = 0;
          if (typeof selector === "string")
              elset = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
          else if (...) 
               .... etc

          this.length = elset.length;
          for ( ; i < this.length; i++) { this[i] = elset[i]; }
          return this;
     }

     Rigged.ajax = Rigged.fn.ajax = function ( obj ) {
          // code here
     }

     window.Rigged = window.$ = Rigged;
}());
```

So, I have no problem with calling `map` method or `each`, but in definition of method called `hide` it prints an error **Uncaught TypeError: current.css is not a function** in console.

When I call `css` in index file like `$("#text").css('display', 'none);` it works, but in `Rigged.prototype` it doesn't work. When I replace line `current.css('display', 'none');` with `current.style.display = 'none';` it normaly works.

Can anybody tell me why `.css` method doesn't work?

**EDITED .map() method**
**+ e (callback) to current**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
       hide: function () {
            // Try to log `this`
            console.log( this );

            /*return this.each(function (current) {
                current.css('display', 'none');
            });*/

            this.css('display', 'none');
        }
```

You're running `.each()` twice when you calling `.hide()`. One within `.hide()` itself and second in `.css()` and this is the problem.

Comment: So, `.map` method is wrong ? I can't use it ? Should I use `this` only in every other method ?

Comment: @Peter `.map()` is not wrong, but I think not necessary to use there, it just taking load of a loop. `.each()` is enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding DOM nodes to the object, not jQuery-like objects, dom nodes.

When you map each of your elements, you pass the **DOM element** to the callback function:

```
results.push(callback.call(this, this[i], i));
//-------------------------------^^^^^^^ here
```

When you do

```
current.css('display', 'none');
```

In your `.hide()` method, you are trying to call `.css()` on a DOM element, which has no such method, so you get an error.

Comment: But what's wrong with it ? I have NO problem with .map() when I call it. Can you tell me how should I replace it?

Comment: I think not. Could you please tell me how to fix it? I'm pretty disgusted when I learned that it's wrong from start